# Trying to figure out this redirection in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is the .htaccess file for one of the sites I am working on. My apache virtualhost is set to redirect http to https automatically. I am running into a problem when I go to my http://www version. It adds index.php in between. Can you see what is wrong here?

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=404]

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

Comment: @anubhava Thanks, but what does it do? Care to explain?

Comment: It did not work. My question is what was your thinking? Why did you think it was the problem?

Comment: Test in Chrome dev tool with **caching disabled** and check in Network tab what are 301/302 redirect URLs you get.

Comment: Never mind as my suggested refactoring didn't work. I will post full answer with detail and reference link if I can figure out what the real problem is.